# RecyclerView Reorder Items with ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback and call notifyDataSetChanged() on Gesture start

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I Have a RecyclerView that lets the user reorder its items when long taping using ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback, the problem is that UX wants to hide a handle on all item views BUT the dragged one, to provide some kind of feedback when the long tap is detected and the card can be dragged.
The issue is that as soon as I try to call notifyDataSetChanged() to make the items update acordingly and hide the handle icon, the Drag functionality stops working.

I tried calling this logic inside the onMove first, and then, inside a ItemTouchListener:onLongClick to try to run this logic and update the recycler before the item gets moved but the same result, as soon as I add a call to notifyDataSetChanged() the drag functionality stops working, any workarrounds to acomplish this functionlity?

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` will invalidate & redraw all items in the list, maybe you should use `notifyItemChanged()` if you want to change some state of only one item.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue: replace the `notifyDataSetChanged` call with 2 calls to `notifyItemRangeChanged(start, end)` to update all views before and after the one being dragged, leaving the dragged one untouched, then the views are updated properlly and the drag gesture is not affected.

This could probably be solved using a DiffCallback too.